# Ensuring that the a circuit breaker in a secondary elec. distribution board will go off before a circuit breaker in the main board

Tags: power-engineering, board

I want to create a small portable single-phase secondary electrical distribution board to safely power up some lights in my back yard.

The board will be powered from a wall socket, and will contain 3 circuit breakers (perhaps a main breaker too) and three output sockets (to connect chains of lights).

Is there a way to ensure that if I get a "short circuit" (between `Live` and `Neutral`) or "leakage" (between `Live` and `ground`), the circuit breaker that will trip will **always** be the one in the secondary board?

I basically would like to avoid tripping breakers in the main board (which would shut down PC, refrigerator etc.).

The circuit breaker of the wall socket is 16Amps, and I was planning to install 10Amp circuit breakers in the secondary board (perhaps, if you think it wise, I'll add a "main" circuit breaker of 16 amps in the 2nd board, too). But will this suffice? If not, is there another way to go about doing this?

The "path" would look like:

```
main board (c.b. 16A) ->
wall socket ->
schuko plug ->
secondary board ->
main c.b. 16A (optional) ->
3x c.b 10A ->
3x output female schuko plugs
```

Note that the secondary box will be located inside the house (and not outside which would render it a hazard on its own!)

Comment: I think the answer is "no, not safely". I can think of some ways that would not pass safety regs.

Comment: @JohnU not safely assume that a 2nday c.b. will always trip? or that the DIY 2ndary board is a not safe idea to start of with ?

Comment: I don't think there's any (safe) way to force one breaker to trip before the other if they are RCD's of the same leakage rating. The over-current trip I'd expect the lowest rated device to trip 1st, but that's a likelihood not a certainty.

Comment: The order of protection device tripping depends on the particular devices in question and the kind of fault being experienced. For overload faults, the breakers will trip in order of ascending rating (roughly speaking.) For earth leakage and short circuit faults, the breakers will probably all operate simultaneously no matter their rating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

[image]

The above is a portable socket-outlet assembly intended for use in the construction industry. This particular model is made by Clipsal for the Australian market. It includes its own 30mA-sensitivity residual current device (ELCB for you folks in the US.)

As a nice extra feature, if you have an electrician terminate matching screw-on plugs to your lights, the assembly will be weatherproof to IP66 when the plugs are in the sockets.

---

Regarding how you want the sub-distribution board to trip off before the main circuit breaker does - this is hard to do.

For overload faults (putting a little bit too much load on one circuit), you should be able to obtain acceptable discrimination by installing a dedicated circuit breaker for this circuit, with a rating half that of the main circuit breaker.

E.g. if your main circuit breaker is 32A, a 16A breaker should provide acceptable discrimination for overload faults.

For full-bore, short circuit faults - these happen so fast that the circuit breakers all race with each other. Typical tripping times for a miniature circuit breaker, under short-circuit fault conditions, are 10ms or less (see below.) You will not be able to obtain discrimination between miniature circuit breakers for a short circuit fault.

[image]
*From Clipsal 4-series MCB catalogue.*

---

Regarding topology, if you were going to go with the 'custom built' approach, rather than buying a portable socket-outlet assembly off the shelf, it should look something like this. Note the sub board should be on a dedicated circuit.

In this drawing I have shown the connection between the main board and the sub board via a socket-outlet, like you specified, but I would highly recommend hardwiring this instead.

[image]

Comment: I guess that `You will not be able to obtain discrimination between miniature circuit breakers for a short circuit fault.` means I cannot realy be sure that the sub-board will trip. right?

Answer (score 2):

If everything downstream is rated for lower breaking capacity compared to upstream then you've done the best you can to achieve your aims. Regards the tripping of a breaker due to leakage to earth use  a "residual current breaker" like this: -

[image]

See [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) for details

Comment: Should I add a main breaker in the 2ndary board , too? or is it completely unnecessary?

Comment: If you want to avoid your original main breaker tripping then you'll need a lower current breaker on your portable distribution board. I'd also put a switch on too because it just may be convenient. The RCD above is to trip if there are earth leakage currents and is necessary (at least in the UK).

Comment: I would expect that in a mechanical breaker there would be a certain amount of time between the moment that enough energy has been absorbed by the breaker to make tripping inevitable, and the point where it actually trips.  I would expect that if the downstream breaker is lower than the primary breaker, moderate overload conditions would trip the downstream one without the upstream one tripping, but severe overloads (e.g. short circuits) could impart enough energy to both breakers to make tripping inevitable before either breaker actually tripped.

Comment: ok how would the path be in the 2ndary board? (input cable -> RCB -> main c.b.16A -> switch -> 3x c.b 10A -> output sockets ?

Comment: I'd have the RCD as last in the chain feeding the output sockets but I haven't read the electrical regulations in a long, long time - probably when ELCBs were used! First in line I'd have an isolation switch, then 16A breaker then RCD then I'd use fuses for each socket. Hey that's just me!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply going to plug your panel into a receptacle in your house I would install a 15amp gfi in the receptacles placed. A gfi device is going to trip first versus a breaker nearly everytime. While its not required by the NEC, I always like to put residential outdoor lighting, especially landscape lighting on gfi protection.